# Complex derivative

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-calculus

The derivative of a function $f(x)$ is the limit of the quotient
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
A formula defining the [fractional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_derivative) of the same function is for example:
$$\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{d(x-a)^{\frac{1}{2}}}f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\pi)}}\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f(\tau)}{\sqrt{(x-\tau})}d\tau$$
My question is:
is it possible to define an imaginary derivative 
$$\frac{d^i}{dx^{i}}f(x)$$ of the function $f(x)$?
Tanks.

Comment: A google search found complex order mentioned here: http://www.uta.cl/charlas/volumen19/Indice/MAUROrevision.pdf and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: E.R. Love "Fractional derivatives of imaginary order." J. London Math. Soc. (2) 3 1971 241–259.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a complex number with $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha) \geq 0$. Then the **Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative** of order $\alpha$ of a function $f(t)$ is given by $$_a D^\alpha_t f(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n - \alpha)} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \int_a^x \frac{f(\tau)}{(t - \tau)^{n-\alpha-1}} ~d\tau,$$ where $n = [\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)] + 1$ and $[\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)]$ is the integer part of $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)$. Note that this definition indeed makes sense for complex $\alpha$ with positive real part, and in particular, $$_a D^i_t f(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1 - i)} \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x \frac{f(\tau)}{(t - \tau)^{-i}} ~d\tau.$$

Comment: There is also the Caputo definition, which performs the differentiation first and the integration last...

Comment: I don't know if the Caputo would work for complex orders: it is _not analytic_ in general. In particular if $f(t) = t$, then its Caputo derivative as a function of the differentiation order as a real number is eventually constant, but not constant over the entire line, thus cannot be analytic.