# Fractal derivative of complex order and beyond

Tags: complex-analysis, fractals, quaternions, fractional-calculus, octonions

Is there some precise definition of "complex (fractal) order derivative" *for all* complex number? I am aware of the Riemann-Liouville fractional definition given here: [Complex derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133494/complex-derivative) but I would like to know if some mathematician has defined a complex order derivative valid without restrictions for all complex number z.

I mean: Is a well-defined definition of such an object possible? I need some refereces about that topic. And related to this question would be the following question: What about a "quaternionic order"/"octonionic order" or maybe a "matricial-order" derivative? Can it be built somehow?Remark: I thought about this extended question when working with the "matrix representation" of complex numbers.