# How would I find the nth derivative of a function, where n is imaginary? What about where n is not a constant?

Tags: derivatives, functional-calculus

Forgive me if this question has already been asked. I was unable to find anything relevant to this question.

The $n$th derivative of a function, $f^n(x)$ is well-defined for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. As well, it can be defined for the case where $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$, (i.e. fractional derivatives). What about in the case where $n\in\mathbb{C}$? What would it mean to take the imaginary derivative of a function?

Similarly, let $n$ be a function of some variable, $x$, (i.e. $n=\cos(x)$). Could you define $f^n(x)=f^{\cos(x)}(x)$? And again, what would it even mean to take the $\cos(x)$th derivative of a function?

As well, if $F'(x)=f(x)$, does $f^{-1}(x)=\int\,f(x)\,dx=F(x)$, where $f^{-1}$ is the negative derivative, and not the inverse?

**Edit:** Duplicates do not answer the final part of this question (i.e. the $\cos(x)$th derivative of a function).

**Edit 2:** It's interesting because, let's say that $f^{-1}(x)=\int\,f(x)\,dx=F(x)$. Operator theory tells us that when we apply two half derivatives in succession to a function (i.e. $D^{\frac{1}{2}}D^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)$, that we obtain the first derivative of that function $f(x)$. This is consistent with the idea that the antiderivative is nothing more than $D^{-1}f(x)=D^{-1}F'(x)$.

But consider the complex derivative $f^i(x)$. Following operator theory, one would claim that the antiderivative of this function could be written as $f^{-i}(x)$. However, this is obviously not the case as this implies that $f(x)=f^0(x)=f'{x}$, recalling that $i^2=-1$, such that $(i)(-i)=1$.

Comment: I know almost nothing about this, but I do know that Fractional Derivatives generalize derivatives of integer order to derivatives of any real order. Worth looking up. I imagine there is a generalization to derivatives of order $z\in\mathbb{C}$ that you will stumble upon during that search. Sorry I can't be of further help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-integer order derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331819/non-integer-order-derivative), also related with [Complex derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133494/complex-derivative?rq=1) and [Fractal derivative of complex order and beyond] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361737/fractal-derivative-of-complex-order-and-beyond?lq=1)

Comment: "What would it mean to take the imaginary derivative of a function?" Mathematical definitions aren't absolute in some objective, external sense; they're created by individual mathematicians to give short names to useful concepts arising in the course of other investigations. Syntactically-meaningful combinations of existing terms do not by themselves make useful definitions. (Example: "What would be the generalization of the complex numbers to three-dimensional space?" gets asked here periodically.) That is, the burden is on _you_ to provide the definition before you can expect an answer. :)